# What is a replacement of deprecated MODE_WORLD_READABLE SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contentprovider, android-preferences

I am developing Android app `A` so that another one `B` could read `A`'s `SharedPreferences`.

In javadoc for `android.content.Context` the following is said about both `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Creating world-writable
>   files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in
>   applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should
>   use more formal mechanism for interactions such as `ContentProvider`,
>   `BroadcastReceiver`, and `Service`.

According to this, `A` shall save its `SharedPreferences` with `MODE_PRIVATE` flag and provide a `ContentProvider`, so that `B` could query `A`'s `ContentProvider`. But how do I know `SharedPreferences` Uri?

I guess it's like `content://authority_name/preference_file_name` but that doesn't work for me. I would appreciate any correct examples.

And in general, is it possible to access other app's `MODE_PRIVATE` `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: no, its not possible to access other app's MODE_PRIVATE Sahredpreferences. You can refer to the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: @Madhu and is it possible to interface SharedPreferences with a ContentProvider if I know Provider's authorities and Preference's filename?

Comment: we can't interface SharedPreferences with a ContentProvider

Comment: Are both the apps developed by you?

Comment: Store the values in a database table using content provider and from there you can get the uri for the table.And from App B access those values from the uri

Comment: @Abdullah, yes, they are.

Comment: @RaviTeja Creating an SQLite db and a ContentProvider just t to store a boolean seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not so private, use sdcard storage.

It is possible to access other app's MODE_PRIVATE Sahredpreferences: they have same uid. that is, same signature and "sharedUserId" in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer (perhaps with code)? Situation is as that I'm using the [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) pattern to notify user of an update. However, from `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.onPerformSync()` method I cannot access the app's default shared preferences using the `Context` passed to that method.

Comment: This answer's suggestions can lead to new difficult to solve problems when the two apps needs to exist and run on the same device...